# PHP cURL "CURLOPT_USERPWD" or best way to protect the API?

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl, file-get-contents

In php cURL usage, what actually is `CURLOPT_USERPWD` working? I can see in many examples, like:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"my_username:my_password");
```

.. but how to do at the Server Side? What actually are those `username` and `password`? Of course since i want to protect my PHP API page at Server Side, is that the best way or what is the best way to protect it please?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have a separate config class that contained your user name and password.  Then you would create a new version of that config class in your file with the cURL commands.  Then you would pass the username and password as variables to the cURL commands.  The cURL information will not be visible anyway as long as it is not echoed or printed. Even if you just put it in directly it would be hidden, but having it in a config file will allow you to change the values without changing the main page that contains the cURL commands.

Comment: Could you please forward me an example? :(

Comment: As long as the curl portion is not printed or echoed it will be hidden.  As for "what is the username and password", those are provided by the developer of the API you are using.  So, if you are using the paypal API, you must set up an account with paypal and they will provide you with a user name and password, and additional keys if necessary.  If it is the imgur API, you will use your own username and password, and they will provide you with any additional keys...and so on.

Comment: No no, i mean, i'm not asking as a client. I will now develop an API. I'm Server. So what does username/password mean to it? HOW can i apply username/password protection in the API for cURL clients?

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't look like you've gotten a better answer.  What you most likely need to be looking at to get a better picture is RESTful Web Services.  This is the common architecture for writing an API of your own.  Most api's need you to connect via SSL and that is what shield the curl credentials when connecting to your API service.  Sorry I couldn't be mor help, but it is a complex problem and you should start with REST, in my opinion.